# Why mocking module in Jest is not an antipattern?

Tags: jestjs

Imagine I have module1.js with only function fn1()

```
function fn1() {
  return 'I am module1.fn1';
}

module.exports = { fn1 }
```

And module2.js with only function main() which calls fn1 from module1.js

```
const { fn1 } = require('./module1')

function main() {
  return fn1();
}

module.exports = {
  main
}
```

and I have written unit test for module2.js

```
const module2 = require('../src/module2');

jest.mock('../src/module1', () => ({
  fn1: () => 'I am mocked result of f1'
}));

describe('Testing module2.main', () => {

  it('Should return value from module_1_mock.fn1', () => {
    const result = module2.main();
    expect(result).toEqual('I am mocked result of f1')
  })
})
```

and then if somebody totally deletes function fn1 from module1 - unit test for module2 still works and passes successfully.

**This is very bad behavior, why is that allowed? Function is completely deleted, it does not exist, but test for module2 is still green. Isn't it a way to get severe bugs?**

**Are there some rules or best practices which guide developers when to use approach A or B?**

approach A - mock module by complete overriding

```
jest.mock('../src/module1', () => ({
  // tests will work even if fn1 is already deleted from module1 
  fn1: () => 'I am mocked result of f1'
}));
```

approach B - mock module without overriding:

```
const module1 = require('../src/module1');
jest.mock('../src/module1');
// it will throw an error if fn1 does not exist in module1
module1.fn1.mockImplementation(() => 'I am mocked result of f1')
```

Comment: If module1 and module2 are considered different units, they are supposed to be tested separately. Isolating them from each other allows to reduce the number of moving parts. They can and likely should be additionally tested together in integration/e2e tests. *Function is completely deleted, it does not exist, but test for module2 is still green. Isn't it a way to get severe bugs?* - not covering module1 unit with tests that could prevent this is surely a way to get bugs.

Comment: But anyway, I don’t understand why there is no recommendation to use approach B by default, to reduce risks. Developers often use A just because it’s less lines to write, but ... risks are huge, in case A.

Comment: The code you posted isn't the same thing as you originally described. B doesn't differ much from A in terms of so-called risk, except that it fails in case fn1 is not there. B uses Jest auto-mocking, it works in undocumented ways that may differ from your expectations. *mock module without overriding* - this is not true as auto-mock replaces all functions with stubs that return undefined. The difference is that if unexpected function fn2 is used with A, it will fail with clear error that says that fn2 is not a function, while B can result in failed expectations that need debugging.